# Error on INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

i got this problem:
i've got three tables:
users     :    Contains all user information and the primary key
gallery   :    Contains a relation between user id and image id
photoes   :    Contains the photo id and the url (where the photo is stored on the server)

here is an example of the three tables

> table name: Users 
>   name_surname            ||   joe   ||  john   || 
>   email                      ||joe@..||  john@..||
>   etc...
>   id (PRIMARY KEY)             ||   1    ||    2    ||
>
> table name: Gallery 
>   id             || 1 || 1 || 
>   image_id                      ||   1    ||    2    || 
>   table name: Photoes
>  
>   id              ||   1          || 2            ||
>   url             ||pht1.jpg||phot2.jpg||

the problem is that i made this query below but it returns null and it should return all url where the user id is like the id of the user logged in the site

```
"SELECT gallery.url
 FROM photoes
 JOIN gallery ON users.id = gallery.id
 JOIN photoes ON gallery.image_id = photoes.id"
```

i think probably the problem is in the INNER JOIN query syntax, can someone help me?
thanks for your future answers
Have a nice Day
Luca

Comment: The query does not even parse. You have `photoes` declared twice and `users` table not at all. And that `ON users.id = gallery.id` should probably be `ON users.id = gallery.user_id`

Comment: And please if at all possible fix the misspelling in the table name of Photos. Your devs will hate you forever if you leave it.

Comment: It's OK to read other people's efforts at asking questions before posting your own.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining photoes [sic] to itself without any mention of the *table* users. Try this instead:

```
SELECT gallery.url
 FROM users
 JOIN gallery ON users.id = gallery.id
 JOIN photoes ON gallery.image_id = photoes.id
```

Incidentally, a more standard name for `gallery.id` would be `gallery.user_id` to show where it is referencing. You may also want to fix the spelling on `photos`.

Comment: Thanks for the spelling issue  but the problem still persist

Comment: To be clear, is the problem that you are getting NULL back (as you said in your question) or that you are getting all records regardless of which user they are attached to? I notice that you said "where the user id is like the id of the user logged in the site" and that is not taken into consideration in any of the queries...